# Hide element in an iframe when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working on my own signature (email) generator. Everything works except one functionality. When a user will check checkbox the field with phone number should dissapear. JS looks as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var imie = $('input[name="imie"]').val(),
            stanowisko = $('input[name="stanowisko"]').val(),
            telefon = $('input[name="telefon"]').val(),
            email = $('input[name="email"]').val();

        var iframe = $('iframe#emailSignature').contents();

        iframe.find('#imie').text(imie);
        iframe.find('#stanowisko').text(stanowisko);
        iframe.find('#telefon').text(telefon);
        iframe.find('#email').attr('href', 'mailto:' + email).text(email);

            $("#hide_phone_no").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    iframe.find("#disable_phone").hide();
                } else {
                    iframe.find("#disable_phone").show();
                }
            });

    });
});
```

id "disable_phone" is related to an object in iframe which is a  with 2x TD's.

Why it doesn't work?

EDIT:
below you can find HTML code for both index.html and iframe content

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    label {
        display: block;
    }
    table {
        border-bottom:10px solid #ffa312;
        margin-bottom:40px;
    }
    #gen_form {
        background:#e6e6e6;
        padding:0 1em;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var imie = $('input[name="imie"]').val(),
                stanowisko = $('input[name="stanowisko"]').val(),
                telefon = $('input[name="telefon"]').val(),
                email = $('input[name="email"]').val();

            var iframe = $('iframe#emailSignature').contents();

            iframe.find('#imie').text(imie);
            iframe.find('#stanowisko').text(stanowisko);
            iframe.find('#telefon').text(telefon);
            iframe.find('#email').attr('href', 'mailto:' + email).text(email);

                $("#hide_phone_no").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        iframe.find("#disable_phone").hide();
                    } else {
                        iframe.find("#disable_phone").show();
                    }
                });

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form autocomplete="off" id="gen_form">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h3>1. Wypełnij formularz:</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="">Imię i nazwisko:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="imie" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="">Stanowisko:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="stanowisko" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="">Numer telefonu (+48 XXX XXX XXX)</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="telefon" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="">Adres email:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="email" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="">Zaznacz pole jeżeli chcesz ukryć telefon:</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="hide_phone_no" name="hidephone">
                    </div>                
                    <br><br>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h3>2. Kliknij w przycisk poniżej:</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="submit">Generuj!</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h3>3. Wykonaj poniższe kroki:</h3>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Kliknij w dowolnym (niepodlinkowanym) miejscu na wygenerowanej niżej stopce</li>
                        <li>CTRL + A i CTRL + C</li>
                        <li>Skopiowaną treść wklej za pomocą CTRL + V w używanym kliencie pocztowym</li>
                    </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Wizualizacja stopki:</p>
    </form>
    <iframe src="email_signature.html" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" id="emailSignature" name="emailSignature"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Then we have an iframe content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="100" valign="middle">
                <a href="https://qubicgames.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://colorfill.pl/qubicgames/qg-logo.jpg" alt="QubicGames" width="90" height="90" style="display:block;border:0;">
                </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: small; line-height:1.5em; color:#000000;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="imie" height="24" valign="top" style="font-size:14px;line-height:1.5em;">
                                Joanna Przykładowa
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="24" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;line-height:1.5em;border-bottom:1px solid #ffa312;">
                                <strong id="stanowisko">Head of Design</strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px; padding-top:5px;line-height:1.5em; color:#000000;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr id="disable_phone">
                                            <td width="27" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ffa312;">
                                                m.
                                            </td>
                                            <td id="telefon">
                                                +48 123 456 789
                                            </td>                                        
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="27" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ffa312;">
                                                e.
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a id="email" href="mailto:j.przykładowa@qubicgames.com" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:underline;">j.przykładowa@qubicgames.com</a>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="27" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ffa312;">
                                                w.
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="https://qubicgames.com" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:underline;">www.qubicgames.com</a>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:10px;line-height:1.5em;font-weight:bold;padding-top:5px;">
                                QubicGames S.A. / Poland
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="44" valign="middle">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="30">
                                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/QubicGamespl" target="_blank">
                                                    <img src="https://colorfill.pl/qubicgames/fb.png" alt="Facebook" width="20" height="20" style="display:block;border:0;">
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="30">
                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/QubicGamespl" target="_blank">
                                                    <img src="https://colorfill.pl/qubicgames/tw.png" alt="Twitter" width="20" height="20" style="display:block;border:0;">
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="30">
                                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/QubicGamespl/" target="_blank">
                                                    <img src="https://colorfill.pl/qubicgames/in.png" alt="Instagram" width="20" height="20" style="display:block;border:0;">
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--<tr>
                            <td style="font-size:8px;line-height:15px;">
                                VikingCO Poland, ul. Tęczowa 13/210, 53-601 Wrocław, <br>NIP: 8971793-639, REGON: 022284492, KRS: 0000484436
                            </td>
                        </tr>-->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you say this is inside an iframe. do you have permissions to access the iframe?

Comment: @cloned - yes indeed. It's a file in the same directory. Other variables are being passed perfectly. Checkbox is the only issue

Comment: can you share your HTMl with Iframe?

Comment: @RaviMakwana - i've edited the original post, adding html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `disable_phone` will only work when

you submit form and after that `hide_phone_no` checkbox check or uncheck

I have fixed this your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var imie = $('input[name="imie"]').val(),
            stanowisko = $('input[name="stanowisko"]').val(),
            telefon = $('input[name="telefon"]').val(),
            email = $('input[name="email"]').val();

        var iframe = $('iframe#emailSignature').contents();

        iframe.find('#imie').text(imie);
        iframe.find('#stanowisko').text(stanowisko);
        iframe.find('#telefon').text(telefon);
        iframe.find('#email').attr('href', 'mailto:' + email).text(email);
        hideShowPhoneNo(iframe)

    });
    $("#hide_phone_no").click(function () {
        var iframe = $('iframe#emailSignature').contents();
        hideShowPhoneNo(iframe)
   });

    function hideShowPhoneNo(iframe){
        if ($("#hide_phone_no").is(":checked")) {
            iframe.find("#disable_phone").hide();
        } else {
            iframe.find("#disable_phone").show();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your 'this' in your callback function. 
Maybe use arrow function or bind it.

Comment: hmm it's weird. I've added alerts to the both states and no alert is showing when form is submited. For the test purposes I've added alert few lines earlier, just to revoke it when submit and it works. so the issue is with 'checked' function..